# Help me identify this component in an RF transmitter

Tags: rf, transmitter, remote-control

This is from a 2-channel RF Transmitter FlySky FS-GT2. I think the antenna's wire should be soldered onto this RF transmitter PCB, flat silver component, however, I do not know where to solder because of this unknown component.

[image: RF Transmitter PCB, flat silver component]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Check connectivity of the silver component to GND first.

Comment: are you referring to the shielding can?

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the shielding can. Amy idea on removing it to what could be underneath

Comment: Removing that can would be challenging. I'd guess the antenna connection is that small dot in the center of the PCB tab protruding from the can (just above your arrow). Looks like there was an RF connector there that broke off.

Comment: If the "antenna wire" is coaxial cable, you'll have to separate the shield and center conductor, solder shield to either larger pad, solder center to small central pad.

Comment: Thank You @MarkLeavitt